# Build and deploy Gatsby site to GitHub Pages --> rendering ReadMe.md or 404

Tags: npm, gatsby, github-pages

I can't get GitHub Pages to display anything other than the ReadMe.md or a 404 page when trying to deploy my Gatsby site to GitHub Pages.

I have the source branch in GH Pages set to `gh-pages`.

The package.json scripts looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "deploy": "gatsby build && gh-pages -d public -b master"
  },
```

I have tried changing that last `master` to `gh-pages` with no success.

In Terminal, I have tried running `npm run deploy` from both the `gh-pages` and `master` branches.

It always builds/deploys without incident.

```
info Done building in 15.341832625 sec


Pages

┌ src/pages/404.js
│ ├   /404/
│ └   /404.html
└ src/pages/index.js
  └   /

  ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
  │                                                                │
  │   (SSG) Generated at build time                                │
  │ D (DSG) Deferred static generation - page generated at runtime │
  │ ∞ (SSR) Server-side renders at runtime (uses getServerData)    │
  │ λ (Function) Gatsby function                                   │
  │                                                                │
  ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

Published
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using any kind of path prefixing or is it deploying in the main domain? How's your page structure (are you creating dynamic pages or manual pages)?

Comment: @FerranBuireu - it's deploying to a custom URL directly to the main domain. I have put `"homepage": "https://www.example.com",` in the package.json as well. And put it in GitHub Pages as well.